# WFS 2.0 transaction

Tags: postgis, geoserver, wfs-t

I am using WFS-T in a mobile application to commit changes to a postgis database via geoserver 2.6. I build the http requests myself (not using any framework like geotools or openlayers). I already support wfs1.1.0 and would like to extend to support for 2.0.0.

I am unable to send a successful commit request so far, reading the standard did not help me find the answer, and I found no examples on the web... Here is my post parameters:

```
<wfs:Transaction version="2.0.0" service="WFS" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xxxxxxx/geoserver/schemas/wfs/2.0/wfs.xsd">
  <wfs:Update typeName="av_dev:CopperCable">
    <wfs:Property>
      <wfs:ValueReference>InsertBy</wfs:ValueReference>
      <wfs:Value>0</wfs:Value>
    </wfs:Property>
    <ogc:Filter>
      <ogc:GmlObjectId gml:id="CopperCable.2" />
    </ogc:Filter>
  </wfs:Update>
</wfs:Transaction>
```

I am getting this error from geoserver:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch

This request works for wfs 1.1.0 if I replace the version number and the "ValueReference" tag with "Name".

What is wrong in my request?

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
<wfs:Update typeName="av_dev:PointModel" >
    <wfs:Property>
      <wfs:ValueReference>orientation</wfs:ValueReference>
      <wfs:Value>2</wfs:Value>
    </wfs:Property>
    <fes:Filter>
      <fes:ResourceId rid="7" />
    </fes:Filter>
  </wfs:Update>
</wfs:Transaction>
```

What has changed is the ogc namespace for the filter was replaced with fes (Filter Encoding Specs.)
The content of the filter is a "ResourceId" element with a "rid" attribute. In my case the rid attribute contains the id of the feature only whereas the example from the standard document contains the feature type plus the id like this: . (so this is still not clear for me).
Also, this working request updates an integer attribute ; I did not manage to update a geometry attribute, so still accepting help.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
<wfs:Update typeName="av_dev:PointModel" >
    <wfs:Property>
      <wfs:ValueReference>orientation</wfs:ValueReference>
      <wfs:Value>2</wfs:Value>
    </wfs:Property>
    <fes:Filter>
      <fes:ResourceId rid="7" />
    </fes:Filter>
  </wfs:Update>
</wfs:Transaction>
```

What has changed is the ogc namespace for the filter was replaced with fes (Filter Encoding Specs.)
The content of the filter is a "ResourceId" element with a "rid" attribute. In my case the rid attribute contains the id of the feature only whereas the example from the standard document contains the feature type plus the id like this: `<featuretype>.<id>` (so this is still not clear for me).
Also, this working request updates an integer attribute ; for geometries, I had to check and change the namespaces (including GML namespace).